# Problem with threads in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I'm writing an application in WPF. I have one main thread and another one - where I calculate something. In main thread I need to do one operation after additional thread will be finished. I can't use Join for additional thread, because I don't want to block main thread. How I can wait for finishing second thread and at the same time don't block main thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The eaisest way is to use the [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and handle the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) event.

I also invite you to take a look Part 3 of 
Joseph Albahari's [Threading in C# pdf](http://www.albahari.com/threading/threading.pdf)

Comment: Hmmm, I think it won't be the best solution. I would like to cancel this additional thread when I click cancel button. I know that background worker has CancelAsync() method, but method that should be done in background worker is running independent. I mean in this function I have no loop which I could break but i just call a system function to optimization and I can't break it.

Comment: @ravenik. Don't you have this problem regardless of which solution you choose? Is  `if (_bw.CancellationPending) { e.Cancel = true; return; }` before setting `e.result` enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

Another easy way is to use Task Parallel Library and chain multiple tasks with [continuations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx).

Though it doesn't exempt you from @Conrad's advice: Read [the threading book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/). It's fascinating and totally worth the efforts.

Comment: @Anvanka +1 continuations are a very nice alternative

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating your own threads, have the worker thread invoke a callback method when it's done:

```
public delegate void DoneDelegate (object calculationResults);
public class MyWorker
{
    public DoneDelegate Done { get; set; }
    public void Go()
    {
        object results = null;
        // do some work
        Done(results);
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public void StartWorker()
    {
        MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
        worker.Done = new DoneDelegate(DoneCallback);
        System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(worker.Go);
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }
    public void DoneCallback (object results)
    {
        // use the results
    }
}
```